# R: mean of all cases with a certain factor level

Tags: r, mean, na

I try the code from here [Mean by factor by level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395366/mean-by-factor-by-level) but it does not work. Here is my situation. From the flights dataset, I want to know the average flight delay of all planes from the carrier UA.

```
library(nycflights13)
data(flights)
mean(flights$air_time[flights$carrier == "UA"])
```

But what results is just

```
[1] NA
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Seems you did nothing wrong, but you can't take the mean if it includes `NA`: `mean(c(1,2,3,NA))`

Comment: Why are you you extracting `air_time` ? Delay is given by `arr_delay` or `dep_delay` for arrival and departure delay respectively. So you can do `mean(flights$arr_delay[flights$carrier == "UA"], na.rm = TRUE)` Or `mean(flights$dep_delay[flights$carrier == "UA"], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @Ronak Shah you are right, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are missing values (`NA`) in the dataset, you need to specify the argument `na.rm = TRUE` within the `mean` function. Otherwise, if at least one value is `NA`, the `mean` function (as well as other functions like `sum`, `min`, `max`, ...) will return `NA`.

```
mean(flights$air_time[flights$carrier == "UA"], na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 211.7914
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the `mean` time for `flights$carrier == "UA"`, you could try a solution in `dplyr` by using `summarise`

This solution takes missing values into account by `na.rm=TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
flights %>% 
  filter(carrier == "UA") %>%
  summarise(., mean(air_time, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ric S says, use `na.rm = TRUE` and keep in mind that when R finds NA values, functions will use it as the main value, so you might have similar problems using many other similar functions such as median, max, min, etc.